# TouchPunch preventing onclick event with jquery UI sortable (mobile only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, onclick, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I'm using Jquery UI with TouchPunch for mobile compatibility, and it seems to be preventing the onclick event for a div within my unordered list item on mobile only. Here is what I tried:

- Setting the distance so there is a 10 pixel dead zone, that didn't work.
- Setting the div with the onclick event to cancel in jquery ui so it does not work for moving the li, no luck.
- Editing the simulateMouseEvent in touchpuch that was suggested on a couple different threads here. That didn't work either.

  I noticed one odd behavior, it seems as though when I tap on the very bottom of the div with the on click event, it triggers. I used chrome to connect to my phone via remote devices and look at the source code being generated, but the size of the div was normal. I was able to recreate the problem in jsfiddle even though it's not mobile friendly (I'm using a Galaxy S6).

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/d1o8y4x1/21/)

```
//Please ignore this code block. Look at the JS Fiddle link above. Stack overflow requires some code if there is a link to jsfiddle in the post. In this case it is not necessary.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your Fiddle console says: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function`

Comment: I removed the line of code that was causing the error, from my main code. Didn't resolve the issue. I didn't think it would though, but a nice try nonetheless. Anyone else?